# Hiera - break results into line items

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm using puppet 3.6.2 and trying to use data out of hiera for a windows patching solution.  I'm on a disconnect network and cannot use WSUS.

I have a file patches.yml, which looks like this:

```yaml
windows::patches:
  - Firefox-Setup-119.0b9.exe
  - KB5007255-x64.msu
  - KB5008285-x64.msu
  - KB5008897-x64.msu
  - KB5009595-x64.msu
  - KB5010395-x64.msu
  - KB5011560-x64.msu
  - KB5012144-x64.msu
```

I have my windowspatches.pp file that looks like this:

```
class profile::windowspatches (
  $filename = hiera("windows::patches")
)
{

  include stdlib

notify{ "$filename": 
  message => $filename
}


#$downloadUrl = "http://server1/Microsoft/"

#package {$patches:
#   ensure => "installed",
#   source => "$downloadUrl+$filename"
#   
#   }

}
```

I'm working through my idea and have the other actions commented out.

The results currently look like this:

Firefox-Setup-119.0b9.exeKB5007255-x64.
msuKB5008285-x64.msuKB5008897-x64.msuKB5009595-x64.msuKB5010395-x64.msuKB5011560
-x64.msuKB5012144-x64.msuKB5012670-x64.msuKB5013616-x64.msuKB5014011-x64.msuKB50
14746-x64.msuKB5015877-x64.msuKB5016683-x64.msuKB5017365-x64.msuKB5018476-x64.ms
uKB5020010-x64.msuKB5020608-x64.msuKB5020902-x64.msuKB5021296-x64.msuKB5022346-x
64.msuKB5022508-x64.msuKB5022894-x64.msuKB5023764-x64.msuKB5025288-x64.msuKB5026
409-x64.msuKB5027109-x64.msuKB5027282-x64.msuKB5028223-x64.msuKB5028974-x64.msuK
B5029304-x64.msuKB5029942-x64.msuKB5030287-x64.msuKB5031407-x64.msu (noop)

I have tired $filename = hiera("windows::patches"), which gives me the same results.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I know I have an old version of puppet and I can't upgrade.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect.  Your array is being converted to a string, in one case because you do that explicitly by interpolating it into a string, and in the other case because that's what `Notify` resources do with their `message` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying an array, and you need to iterate trough this array or maybe change the data structure.

**Solution for OLD puppet servers**

You may try changing your data structure in Hiera as follows:

```yaml
---
download_url: 'http://server1/Microsoft'
windows::patches:
  apache2:
    source: "%{hiera('download_url')}/apache2"
  fping:
    source: "%{hiera('download_url')}/fping"
```

**Please** ensure that `%{hiera('download_url')}` works with your version of puppet and hiera.
If it errors, you shuold change it as follows:

```yaml
---
windows::patches:
  apache2:
    source: "http://server1/Microsoft/apache2"
  fping:
    source: "http://server1/Microsoft/fping"
```

and your puppet manifest will look like this (according to the Puppet language style guide, you should not use lookup in the class parameters):

```rb
class profile::windowspatches {
  $defaults = { 'ensure' => 'installed', }
  $filename = hiera('windows::patches')

  create_resources(package, $filename, $defaults)
}
```

**Solution for RECENT puppet servers**

If you did not have such an old version of puppet, you could stick with your data structure in hiera, and you could have done as following (with 2 bonus tips):

```rb
class profile::windowspatches {
  $filename = lookup("windows::patches", Array, 'first', [])  # hiera command is deprecated
  $download_url = "http://server1/Microsoft/"  # no CamelCase with puppet

  $filename.each | $patch | {
    package { $patch:
      ensure => installed,
      source => "${download_url}${patch}";
    }
  }
}
```

**p.s.**: I'd also recommend to **not** use the double colon separator in the key names in hiera, unless you're using the autolookup feature. It will help distinguishing between auto-lookup and normal lookup.

Let's use `windows_patches` instead of `windows::patches`

Comment: "*`hiera` command is pretty old*" -- yes, and so is Puppet 3, which the OP is using.  There is no `lookup()` function in that (obsolete) version of Puppet.

Comment: Nor is there `each()` or blocks.

Comment: ouch... you're right! I didn't read it was puppet 3.6.2....

Comment: Are you sure that Hiera old enough to be supported on Puppet 3 provided for interpolation tokens using nested lookup, as in `"%{hiera('download_url')}/apache2"`?  My own recollection here is dim, but I think Puppet 3 stopped at Hiera 2, and I think such interpolations were a later addition.

Comment: you might be right. I am not sure (and I thought about it while I was writing the answer). But who can test it with such an old version of puppet? I should search for an archived documentation. I can add a notice...

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using puppet 3.6.2

Don't, if you can possibly avoid it.  Puppet 3 is obsolete, many years past its end of life.  As I write this, the current release version is Puppet 8.3.1.

Although Perforce seems to try to project a different impression on its main web pages, current Puppet is still available as an open-source, no-charge option.  This has all the core features and can be used indefinitely on as many machines as you like.

---

Even if you feel constrained to stick with Puppet 3, ***this* is a bit absurd**:

> ```
> class profile::windowspatches (
>   $filename = hiera("windows::patches")
> )
> {
> ```

Perhaps **the** most significant advance of Puppet 3 over Puppet 2.7 was automatic data binding, which you could and should leverage to associate external data with class parameters.  There are two possibilities here:

1. You have a class somewhere whose fully-qualified name is `windows` and which has a class parameter named `patches`:

   ```
   class windows($patches) {
     # ...
   }
   ```

   In this case, your patch filenames from your current data will be bound automatically to variable `$windows::patches`, which you can ensure is available to you by `include`ing that class":

   ```
   class profile::windowspatches {
     include stdlib
     include windows
     # ... use $windows::patches ...
   }
   ```
2. In the more likely case that you do not have such a `windows` class, you would be better off leveraging automatic data binding directly in your `profile::windowspatches` class.  This would require changing the Hiera key to which the data are bound:

   ```yaml
   profile::windowspatches::filename:
     - Firefox-Setup-119.0b9.exe
     - KB5007255-x64.msu
     - KB5008285-x64.msu
     - KB5008897-x64.msu
     - KB5009595-x64.msu
     - KB5010395-x64.msu
     - KB5011560-x64.msu
     - KB5012144-x64.msu
   ```

   Then, you would just let the data binding do its job:

   ```
   class profile::windowspatches($filename) {
     include stdlib
     # ... use $filename ...
   }
   ```

---

But **the main question** seems to be about iterating over those data once loaded.  Later versions of the Puppet language offer built-in means to iterate over items, and the stdlib module has long had some help there, but the basic means to do iteration in Puppet 3 was to use the fact that when an array is used as a resource title, multiple resources are declared, one for each element.  At its most basic, that might be something like this:

```
class profile::windowspatches (
  $filename
) {

  # Note: do not quote $filename if you want it to be interpreted as an
  # array of resource titles:
  notify { $filename:
    message => ''
  }
}
```

There are lots of other ways to leverage that, many of them involving using defined types to wrap up the logic to be applied iteratively.  You quickly get to that point if you want the iterative body to do different things for different elements.  For example:

```
define profile::windowspatches::notify_one() {
  notify{ "$title": 
    # different message per resource title:
    message => "$title"
  }
}

class profile::windowspatches (
  $filename
) {
  # Note: do not quote $filename if you want it to be interpreted as an
  # array of resource titles:
  profile::windowspatches::notify_one { $filename: }
}
```

Comment: it might not be up to him to upgrade the puppet server. BTW I'd rather use a different data structure and use create_resource. There is no "puppet inc.". There is "Perforce" :p

Comment: @maxadamo, "if you can possibly avoid it" already acknowledges that the OP may *not* be able to avoid using Puppet 3, in which case everything following applies.  Of course, there *used* to be a Puppet, Inc..  I have updated the company name, thanks.  As for `create_resources()` (note spelling), I have always disliked it, and in the general case, it is not as flexible as the more traditional (albeit now obsolete) approach I have presented in this answer.

Comment: you can check my modified answer: it's one line with `create_resources()` . I also didn't like it too much, but it was the most viable alternative back in the days. What do you do with the "flexibility" in such case? It's slightly annoying that you need to define hashes, but it works.